# needrestart keeps restarting some failed services

Tags: linux, debian, debian-stretch, xrdp

I get this message in logs:

Jan 16 06:01:02 examplehost systemd[1]: xrdp-sesman.service: Unit entered failed state.

This may stem from the fact that I disconnected from `xrdp` session without logging out.

OK, so I run `needrestart`. It keeps restarting the service over and over:

```
root@examplehost ~ % needrestart 
Scanning processes...                                                                                     
Scanning candidates...                                                                                    
Scanning processor microcode...                                                                           
Scanning linux images...                                                                                  

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

Restarting services...
 systemctl restart xrdp.service

Service restarts being deferred:
 /etc/needrestart/restart.d/dbus.service
 systemctl restart libvirtd.service
 systemctl restart systemd-journald.service
 systemctl restart systemd-logind.service

No containers need to be restarted.

User sessions running outdated binaries:
 root @ session #1: login[743]
 root @ session #626: sshd[19524]
 root @ user manager service: systemd[1208]
root@examplehost ~ % 
root@examplehost ~ % 
root@examplehost ~ % 
root@examplehost ~ % 
root@examplehost ~ % 
root@examplehost ~ % needrestart 
Scanning processes...                                                                                     
Scanning candidates...                                                                                    
Scanning processor microcode...                                                                           
Scanning linux images...                                                                                  

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

Restarting services...
 systemctl restart xrdp.service

Service restarts being deferred:
 /etc/needrestart/restart.d/dbus.service
 systemctl restart libvirtd.service
 systemctl restart systemd-journald.service
 systemctl restart systemd-logind.service

No containers need to be restarted.

User sessions running outdated binaries:
 root @ session #1: login[743]
 root @ session #626: sshd[19524]
 root @ user manager service: systemd[1208]
```

How do I fix that (without rebooting)? And why restarting `xrdp` does not seem to work (manually too)?

OS: Debian 9.6 amd64.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stopping and starting the service?
Since you disconnected, there might be a zombie process hanging around. If it can't stop, you could attempt a kill or even a kill -9.